# Mssql encoding problem with special characters

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, node-mssql

We are using the node-mssql package to insert into and read out of our azure mssql database.
The database is very simple, because it is just used as a key/value cache, where the value can be quite long and also contain special characters.

DB Schema:

```
create table cache
(
    id       int identity
        constraint cache_pk
            primary key nonclustered,
    cacheKey varchar(500),
    ttl      bigint,
    value    varchar(max)
)
go

create index cache_cacheKey_index
    on cache (cacheKey desc)
go

create index cache_ttl_index
    on cache (ttl)
go
```

For some reason, when I insert values into "value", some special characters are not treated well.

```
Dash – example
```

turns into:

```
Dash  example
```

I have seen the same thing happening with the french apostrophe.
I also tried to change the collation already, but that did not help.
Also tried it by using `nvarchar(max)` as column type.

This is the insert code (including the sql):

```
  const result = await conn.request()
                      .input('key', mssql.VarChar, key)
                      .input('value', mssql.Text, value)
                      .input('ttl', mssql.BigInt, cacheEndTime)
                      .query`INSERT INTO cache (cacheKey, value, ttl) VALUES (@key, @value, @ttl)`;
```

Can you please help with a correct table structure or sql statement to make this work?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that value, so that suggest you have something that is stripping that value somewhere. A literal `INSERT` works fine: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=866b053eb93894239480cfdf9ddc2f87)

Answer (score 2):

The answer for your question are in one of this items:

- Server collation
- Table collation
- Field collation
- Cast the insert text

For example, if you create nvarchar (I recommend if you have international scenario) field, cast the text insert like N'text to insert'.

It will work ;)

Comment: How would I cast the type with these dynamic @values?

Comment: If the character were one outside of the code page of the server's collation, the OP wouldn't be getting the behaviour they are. `'Dash – example'` wouldn't result in `'Dash  example'`, it would result in `'Dash ? example'`. This isn't a code page issue, or at least it isn't at SQL Server's end.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if can help you, but have you checked the collation of the table, the database, and the server? The collate have differents levels.

Comment: Can you maybe provide an example of how the code would look like correctly created with collation? I am not sure which one to use or how to set it. We are using Azure. I guess the collation should be correct there.

Comment: Run the following command to change the character set and collation of your database:

ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

Run the following command to change the character set and collation of your table:

ALTER TABLE tablename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

Comment: thanks @RealSeik . Unfortunately I get the following error: Invalid collation 'utf8_general_ci'

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.
Like @RealSeik and @Larnu already stated it was probably not a problem with the database or the queries themselves, but rather an input problem.

I realized, that `node-sass` has a type for Unicode text, where they took care of casting it correctly.
So instead of `mssql.Text` I changed it to `mssql.NText`.

So now the insert command looks as follows:

```js
  const result = await conn.request()
                      .input('key', mssql.VarChar, key)
                      .input('value', mssql.NText, value)
                      .input('ttl', mssql.BigInt, cacheEndTime)
                      .query`INSERT INTO cache (cacheKey, value, ttl) VALUES (@key, @value, @ttl)`;
```

I have also added collations to my other scripts, for good measure as well.
(that alone did not help, but for good measure)

```
    ALTER DATABASE MyDbName  
    COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8 ;  
    
    create table cache
    (
        id       int identity
            constraint cache_pk
                primary key nonclustered,
        cacheKey varchar(500) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8,
        ttl      bigint,
        value    varchar(max) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8
    )
    go
    
    create index cache_cacheKey_index
        on cache (cacheKey desc)
    go
    
    create index cache_ttl_index
        on cache (ttl)
    go
```